# Adding files to a Tar Archive in PHP with different filenames

Tags: php, pear, tar

I'm currently using the [`Archive-Tar Pear extension`](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar) for PHP to add a collection of files into a Tar Archive.

These files are stored on a filer with an extra extension 
e.g.

```
 filename.tgz.104850209.t or filename2.doc.2154395.t
```

I'd like to remove this extra extension while adding the files so that my Tar Archive would have the files: filename.tgz and filename2.doc

Is there a way of doing that without having to **copy/rename** the source files first before adding to the Archive?

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 2):

`Archive_Tar` in its latest version does not yet support such a functionality out of the box. Part of the functionality is in `_addFile()` and the other part in `_addString()`.

Most easy is probably to extend from `Archive_Tar` and proxy all calls to [`_writeHeaderBlock()`](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_Archive_Tar__Archive_Tar-1.3.11ArchiveTar.php.html#a1182) which is public, applying a map on the filename parameter so to rename it when written into headers.

```
class Patched_Archive_Tar extends Archive_Tar
{
    var $renameMap = array();

    function _writeHeaderBlock($p_filename, $p_size, $p_mtime=0, $p_perms=0,
                               $p_type='', $p_uid=0, $p_gid=0)
    {
        return parent::_writeHeaderBlock($this->_translateFilename($p_filename), 
                                  $p_size, $p_mtime=0, $p_perms=0,
                                  $p_type='', $p_uid=0, $p_gid=0);
    }

    function _translateFilename($orignal)
    {
        $map = $this->renameMap;
        if (isset($map[$orignal])) {
            return $map[$orignal];
        }

        return $original;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$obj = new Patched_Archive_Tar('dummy.tar'); // name of archive

$files = array('mystuff/ad.gif', 
               'mystuff/alcon.doc.t', 
               'mystuff/alcon.xls.t');   // files to store in archive

$obj->renameMap = array(
    'mystuff/alcon.doc.t' => 'mystuff/alcon.doc',
    'mystuff/alcon.xls.t' => 'mystuff/alcon.xls',
)  // files to rename

if ($obj->create($files)) {
    echo 'Created successfully!';
} else {
    echo 'Error in file creation';
}
```

This is quick and dirty but hopefully worky. For something better see the function I noticed at the beginning `_addFile()` and `_addString()`, you basically want another one that is able to add a file (as with `_addFile()`) by specifiying the filename (as with `_addString()`).

Comment: Thanks. Although it looks like _writeHeaderBlock is only called when using _addString() and not _addFile() so that wouldn't work here. But your second point looks like the way to go, to extend and a function to be able to add files with a modifier.

Comment: _addFile() should call _writeHeader() which then should call _writeHeaderBlock(). Doesn't it?

Comment: @duckboy81: Thanks for your edit proposal. Makes perfect sense to me. /ref: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12939455

Answer (score 0):

Tried to edit @hakre's answer, but peer reviewers weren't having that.

To answer @user2248522's comment, I rewrote the class to use _writeHeader. Additionally, I added a block for any Windows users out there and fixed a couple spelling errors.

```
class Patched_Archive_Tar extends Archive_Tar
{
    var $renameMap = array();

    function _writeHeader($p_filename, $p_stored_filename)
    {
        return parent::_writeHeader($p_filename, 
            $this->_translateFilename($p_stored_filename));
    }

    function _translateFilename($orignal)
    {
        $map = $this->renameMap;

        if (isset($map[$original])) {
            return $map[$original];
        }

        //Need alter our map array to match the altered original on WIN systems
        if (defined('OS_WINDOWS') && OS_WINDOWS) {

            //Check for a proper array
            if (!is_array($map)) return $original;

            //Check each replacement rule
            foreach($map as $needle => $replacement) {

                if ($this->_translateWinPath($needle, true) == $original) {

                    return $replacement;

                } //if()

            } //foreach()

        } //if()

        return $original;

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$obj = new Patched_Archive_Tar('dummy.tar'); // name of archive

$files = array('mystuff/ad.gif', 
               'mystuff/alcon.doc.t', 
               'mystuff/alcon.xls.t');   // files to store in archive

$obj->renameMap = array(
    'mystuff/alcon.doc.t' => 'mystuff/alcon.doc',
    'mystuff/alcon.xls.t' => 'mystuff/alcon.xls',
)  // files to rename

if ($obj->create($files)) {
    echo 'Created successfully!';
} else {
    echo 'Error in file creation';
}
```