# Cannot zip more than 4GB, cannot tar with filenames > 100 characters, what's next?

Tags: php

I am trying to rebuild a backup system that currently zips boatloads of files for easy archiving (using PHP's `ZipArchive` class). The problem I'm having is that `ZipArchive` only supports files up to 4GB.

I thought I found a solution: `PharData`

But the `PharData` class comes with its own problems, namely, filenames cannot be greater than 100 characters for `tar` archives.

I've read about solutions for command line users (`Zip64` and extended headers for `tar` files), but I don't see solutions built-in or that are native to PHP.

Am I missing the right tool for the job? Or is this a common roadblock?

Thank you!
(I'm horrible at making question titles, sorry!)

Edit: The files I am backing up are stored on the server with a random string of text and the real filename is repopulate when the files are zipped. I'm concerned about passing user submitted filenames to my Linux command line.

Comment: or use an `exec` use the linux commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PharData` is meant to be used as part of [the Phar PHP application archiving format](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php). It's not intended for general use.

Use [the Archive_Tar PEAR class](https://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Tar/) to create tar archives.

Comment: Extending Archive_Tar and override _writeHeader seems to complete this solution. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15831608/3101412

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell scripting, create bash script with couple of shell commands to make .tar of all the files using Linux built in command.

This link might be useful to read further

http://broexperts.com/2012/06/how-to-backup-files-and-directories-in-linux-using-tar-cron-jobs/